# Symfony2: Username in URL

Tags: php, model-view-controller, symfony, routes

This issue is very common appears here in SO many times but not for Symfony2 framework. I want to create a rout that take the username directly after the domain to have access to the the user profile, like that: `domain.com/username`. Rout should be:

```
Profile:
    pattern: /{pseudo}
    defaults: { _controller: **Bundle:Default:member }
```

However it's clear that this rout will much other routs like `/main`, too bad. Documentation says that we can make some restriction to the pattern like making pseudo to be exactly En or Fr:

```
Profile:
    pattern: /{pseudo}
    requirements:
        pseudo:  en|fr
```

I may use this to make pseudo not equals to other similar routs like `main , messages , post , blog` but also I have much routs, router will look ugly. If this is a valid way, please show how to make requirements should *not equal* `main, messages,...`
Or there is another way, I'll be thankful to know it.

Comment: The common way it to move `Profile` route down in the `routing.yml`

Comment: From documentation: "The Symfony router will always choose the first matching route it finds". I tried it but forgot to clear the cache before. That works. Thanks a lot thecatontheflat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably should not restrict it on the routing level but on the user register process. If you place the `/{pseudo}` route **after** all the other routes (like your `/main` or `/messages` route) the pattern only matches all requests that do not match any of your other routes.

e.g.

```
main:
    pattern: /main
    defaults:  { _controller: YourBundle:Main:show }

% put all the other routes here

% your very last route
pseudo:
    pattern: /{pseudo}
    defaults:  { _controller: YourBundle:User:show }
```

You may also add a requirement to that last route to contain only e.g. 8 characters and only alphanumeric values or whatever you like with regular expressions.

```
requirements:
    pattern: ^\[a-z0-9]{,8}$
```

However, iff you really want to restrict access via requirements, you may just add a requirement regular expression which disallows some names. Nonetheless I'd highly recommend not to:

```
requirements:
    pattern: ^(?!main|messages|...)$
```

This is also explained in detail in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html).